# I would like to use the same random string in various tests Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have a test to create an account and would like to use the same data to delete the account. I am using random string. I use Nunit and Page Object Model. How can I use the same random string in different tests?

Comment: If you use Random to generate your random strings - just use the same seed everytime (new Random(<your seed here>)). Then on each subsequent run the same sequence of strings will be generated.

Comment: A word of caution, many test frameworks don't guarantee the order of test execution without some extra work, because they encourage that each test can be run independently. Another approach would be storing some test data in an external data source like a database, but again, be careful about having some tests depend on others.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted this to be automated... you would have to do the 'deleting' within the test that does the 'creating', possibly as a cleanup operation. Store the random string as a variable and utilise that. If automation of the delete functionality isn't possible then output the random string so you can manually clean up.